# Rotation axis of a coil in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Given an asymmetrical coil rotating in a uniform constant magnetic field, does the current flowing in it differ if i change the rotation axis (keeping it on the coil plane), mantaining rotational speed always the same?

Comment: Why should there be *any* current? You haven't fully explained the set-up.

Comment: You are right, i edited it

Comment: What does asymmetrical coil mean?

Comment: I better explain myself: if you have a coil with no axis of simmetry and induction due to a uniform constant magnetic field, does the current flowing in it depend on the rotation axis or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current flowing depends on the EMF, which depends on the rate of change of the projected area of the coil, which does not depend on the orientation of the rotation axis